# rewrite get parameters with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, url-rewriting

I am knocking my head how to rewrite get parameters with htaccess.

Here is my htaccess so far (removing only index.php).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to rewrite the following url http://example.com/?lang=en&dscroll=1200 into http://example.com/en/dscroll/1200. Some htaccess master, please :)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule that you have doesn't remove the index.php, it only redirects to a host without the `www` in front.

As for the other rewrite, you need 2. First, you need to make sure your links in all of your content looks like this:

```
http://example.com/en/dscroll/1200
```

instead of the one that has the query string.

Then you need to add, below the rule that you already have, these 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?lang=([^&]+)&([^=&\ ]+)=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?lang=$1&$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yep, that was it :). Thank you Jon!

Comment: i have a same problem, can u review my post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764820/how-can-i-redirect-lang-en-to-en/56770413#56770413